# Magento product filter collection

Tags: product, filter

I am developing a project with custom module of my own.There is a situation i want to filter all the products of the store with my custom logic having data provided by each user from the cookie.Other products will not be displayed in any part of the website to the same user.Whether it is related products block or from any slider etc.Which model should i overwrite in order to filter default product collection ?

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection

Comment: what is that ??

Comment: I have tried to overwrite _applyProductLimitations()

Comment: BUt i cant figure it out how to filter the products

Comment: You need this in which page ? It is a custom page ? or it is a product view page ? or it is product list page ? Please elaborate your question with detailed description of what you need. Currently this question is very limitted and can't give you a proper direction

Comment: I have mentioned "Other products will not be displayed in any part of the website". I want the filter will be applied to every blocks or every pages.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a single function,or i have to manually code in every possible pages?

Comment: You will have your work cut out for you. There's no central place this can be done. Collections are containers and they have several methods to let the programmer select what goes in them. You'll need to return something sane for all these methods and not actually do what is asked. Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection is the starting point, but you'll need to work your way up all it's parents. Seems smarter to just create a special collection based on your logic and in each block use that collection, as I'm pretty sure that the admin will be useless after you do all the work in core.

Comment: Thanks Melvyn.So according to your recommendation i should have to do it manually in every pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to apply your own filtering in all product collection, then the best way would be listen to the event `catalog_product_collection_load_before`. This event will called in every product load operation.

In your module, first you need to setup this event. So add this content inside your module's `config.xml`

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
   <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_modulename>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>applyCustomFilter</method>
                    </namespace_modulename>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_collection_load_before>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <namespace_modulename>
               <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model</class>
            </namespace_modulename>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now define your observer class like this

File : `app/code/local/Namespace/Modulename/Model/Oberver.php`

```
<?php
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
     public function applyCustomFilter($observer)
     {
            $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

            //you got collection above now perform filtering here.
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter(...);

            return $this;
     }
}
```

Any filtering that you apply inside `applyCustomFilter()` will then affect every product collections.

Hope that will help you.

[*This answer is a part of #mageStackDay. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/*]

Comment: Hi this helped me a lot but the handler should be catalog_product_collection_load_before

Comment: If it helped, then feel free to accept it

Comment: Hi @RajeevKTomy, It worked for me in this way, but the layered navigation filters doesn't match with the filtered collection, do you what else can I do?

Comment: @BetoCastillo Can you try this event `catalog_block_product_list_collection`  instead of above-mentioned event? This probably works for you.

Comment: With that event, the collection is not getting affected :(

Comment: @RajeevKTomy How to add website filter in observer?